# Change swagger 2.0 docs path url

Tags: node.js, typescript, swagger

This is how I configure swagger :

```
 const openapi = Openapi.initialize({
    paths: openApiPaths,
    app,
    apiDoc,
  });
  const openApiSpec = openapi.apiDoc;

  console.log(openApiSpec);

  app.use(swaggerUI(openApiSpec));
```

How can I change the base path `/docs/` to `/projectName/docs/` ?

I did not find any relevant answer to that

> EDIT

My api doc is described as below in it's own file:

```
export const apiDoc = {
  'x-express-openapi-additional-middleware': [checkBodyValidity],
  swagger: '2.0',
  basePath: '/api/v1',
  info: {
    title: 'Documentation Rest API',
    version: 'v1',
  },
  paths: {},
  definitions: {}
}
```

CheckBodyValidity is kind of a middleware that check request params validity (not relevant for my question):

```
export const checkBodyValidity: any = (req, res, next) => {}
```

Swagger is initialized as below in a file named openapiSetup :

```
export async function init(app: any): Promise<any> {

[...]

  const openapi = Openapi.initialize({
    paths: openApiPaths,
    app,
    apiDoc,
  });
  const openApiSpec = openapi.apiDoc;

  app.use(swaggerUI(openApiSpec));

}
```

-> openApiPaths is the path{} part if the doc. It's constructed from directories and file names

Finally in express app :

```
await openapiSetup.init(app);
```

Answer (score 3):

What do you have in your YAML? Should be able to update your path by modifying:

```
# Relative URL to external documentation
externalDocs:
  url: /docs
  description: Find more info here
```

More info [here][1]

Edit:

Did you try adding the following to your apiDoc object.

```
export const apiDoc = {
  'x-express-openapi-additional-middleware': [checkBodyValidity],
  swagger: '2.0',
  basePath: '/api/v1',
  info: {
    title: 'Documentation Rest API',
    version: 'v1',
  },
  paths: {},
  definitions: {},
  externalDocs: {
     description: "Docs",
     url: "http://url/projectName/docs"
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't have a yaml and I use swagger 2.0, I'll edit my question with more infos

Comment: At which level do a place "url:" ?  Same level as "paths:"  ?